# Local and Global variables with different Files

Tags: python, arrays, function, variables, scope

In floor_algorithm.py I have a function called `make_floor_outline` which cycles through some other functions in the same file as `make_floor_outline` and outputs some arrays which I use in my `game`function in a separate folder. If I call `make_floor_outline` at the end of algorithm.py the `game` function runs fine, but if I call `make_floor_outline` in the `game` function, or anywhere within the file that the `game` function is in, I get an error saying the arrays im trying to use from `make_floor_outline`are not defined. Why could this be? floor_algorithm.py...

```
def floor_room_IDs():
    global floor_roomIDs
    rand_ID = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
    r_y = 0
    for Layer in floor_roomIDs:
        r_x = 0
        for Tile in Layer:
            floor_roomIDs[r_y][r_x] = floor_map[r_y][r_x]
            r_x += 1
        r_y += 1
    r_y = 0
    for Layer in floor_roomIDs:
        r_x = 0
        for Title in Layer:
            if floor_roomIDs[r_y][r_x] == '1':
                room_ID = rand_ID.pop(random.randint(0, len(rand_ID)-1))
                room_ID_level = globals()['r' + str(room_ID)]
                roomC_ID = 'rc' + str(room_ID)
                globals()['rc' + str(room_ID)] = room_ID_level.copy()            
                floor_roomIDs[r_y][r_x] = str(roomC_ID)
            if floor_roomIDs[r_y][r_x] == 2:
                floor_roomIDs[r_y][r_x] = 'r2'
            if floor_roomIDs[r_y][r_x] == '3':
                floor_roomIDs[r_y][r_x] = 'r3'            
            r_x += 1
        r_y += 1    
def floor_doors():
    global floor_map
    r_y = 0
    for Layer in floor_map:
        r_x = 0
        for Tile in Layer:
            if floor_map[r_y][r_x] == '1' or floor_map[r_y][r_x] == 2:
                door_right = False
                door_bottom = False
                door_left = False 
                door_top = False
                if r_x < 8:
                    if floor_map[r_y][r_x+1] != '/':
                        door_right = True
                if r_y < 8:
                    if floor_map[r_y+1][r_x] != '/':
                        door_bottom = True 
                if r_x > 0:
                    if floor_map[r_y][r_x-1] != '/':
                        door_left = True 
                if r_y > 0:
                    if floor_map[r_y-1][r_x] != '/':
                        door_top = True
                if door_top == True:
                    floor_map[r_y][r_x] = 'a'
                if door_left == True:
                    floor_map[r_y][r_x] = 'b'
                if door_bottom == True:
                    floor_map[r_y][r_x] = 'c'   
                if door_right == True:
                    floor_map[r_y][r_x] = 'd'     
                if door_top == True and door_left == True:
                    floor_map[r_y][r_x] = 'e' 
                if door_top == True and door_bottom == True:
                    floor_map[r_y][r_x] = 'f' 
                if door_top == True and door_right == True:
                    floor_map[r_y][r_x] = 'g'   
                if door_left == True and door_bottom == True:
                    floor_map[r_y][r_x] = 'h'
                if door_left == True and door_right == True:
                    floor_map[r_y][r_x] = 'i'  
                if door_bottom == True and door_right == True:
                    floor_map[r_y][r_x] = 'j'  
                if door_top == True and door_left == True and door_right == True:
                    floor_map[r_y][r_x] = 'k'   
                if door_top == True and door_bottom == True and door_right == True:
                    floor_map[r_y][r_x] = 'l'    
                if door_left == True and door_bottom == True and door_right == True:
                    floor_map[r_y][r_x] = 'm'
                if door_top == True and door_bottom == True and door_left == True:
                    floor_map[r_y][r_x] = 'n'
                if door_top == True and door_bottom == True and door_right == True and door_left == True:
                    floor_map[r_y][r_x] = 'o'                 
            r_x += 1        
        r_y += 1  
        
                            
                                
def floor_validate(): 
    global room_amount
    room_amount = 0
    end_room = 0
    r_y = 0
    for Layer in floor_map:
        r_x = 0
        for Tile in Layer: 
            if floor_map[r_y][r_x] == '1':
                room_amount += 1
            if r_y == 0 or r_y == 1 or r_y == 8 or r_y == 7 or r_x == 0 or r_x == 1 or r_x == 8 or r_x == 7:
                if floor_map[r_y][r_x] == '1':
                    if end_room == 0:
                        if r_y == 8 and r_x != 8 and r_x != 0:
                            if floor_map[r_y-1][r_x] == '1':
                                end_room += 1
                            if floor_map[r_y][r_x+1] == '1':
                                end_room += 1
                            if floor_map[r_y][r_x-1] == '1':
                                end_room += 1
                        if r_y == 0 and r_x != 8 and r_x != 0:
                            if floor_map[r_y+1][r_x] == '1':
                                end_room += 1
                            if floor_map[r_y][r_x+1] == '1':
                                end_room += 1 
                            if floor_map[r_y][r_x-1] == '1':
                                end_room += 1         
                        if r_x == 0 and r_y != 8 and r_y != 0:
                            if floor_map[r_y+1][r_x] == '1':
                                end_room += 1
                            if floor_map[r_y-1][r_x] == '1':
                                end_room += 1 
                            if floor_map[r_y][r_x+1] == '1':
                                end_room += 1    
                        if r_x == 8 and r_y != 8 and r_y != 0:
                            if floor_map[r_y+1][r_x] == '1':
                                end_room += 1
                            if floor_map[r_y-1][r_x] == '1':
                                end_room += 1 
                            if floor_map[r_y][r_x-1] == '1':
                                end_room += 1                      
                        if r_y == 0 and r_x == 0:
                            if floor_map[r_y+1][r_x] == '1':
                                end_room += 1
                            if floor_map[r_y][r_x+1] == '1':
                                end_room += 1
                        if r_y == 0 and r_x == 8:
                            if floor_map[r_y+1][r_x] == '1':
                                end_room += 1
                            if floor_map[r_y][r_x-1] == '1':
                                end_room += 1 
                        if r_y == 8 and r_x == 0:
                            if floor_map[r_y-1][r_x] == '1':
                                end_room += 1
                            if floor_map[r_y][r_x+1] == '1':
                                end_room += 1      
                        if r_y == 8 and r_x == 8:
                            if floor_map[r_y-1][r_x] == '1':
                                end_room += 1
                            if floor_map[r_y][r_x-1] == '1':
                                end_room += 1    
                        if end_room > 1:
                            end_room = 0
                        if end_room == 1:
                            floor_map[r_y][r_x] = 2
                            
                        
            r_x += 1
        r_y += 1
    if room_amount < 18 or room_amount > 22 or end_room != 1:
        make_floor_outline()
    else:
        floor_room_IDs()
        floor_doors()
        
def make_floor_outline():
    global floor_map
    global floor_roomIDs
    read = [['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
            ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
            ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
            ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
            ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
            ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
            ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
            ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
            ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/']]
    
    floor_map = [['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
             ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
             ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
             ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
             ['/','/','/','/','3','/','/','/','/'],
             ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
             ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
             ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
             ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/']]
    floor_roomIDs = [['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
             ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
             ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
             ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
             ['/','/','/','/','3','/','/','/','/'],
             ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
             ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
             ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/'],
             ['/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/','/']]
    for i in range(0, 17):
        r_y = 0
        for Layer in floor_map:
            r_x = 0
            for Tile in Layer:
                if Tile == '3':
                    floor_map[r_y][r_x+1] = '1'
                    floor_map[r_y][r_x-1] = '1'
                    floor_map[r_y+1][r_x] = '1'
                    floor_map[r_y-1][r_x] = '1'
                if Tile == '1':
                    if read[r_y][r_x] == '/':
                        read[r_y][r_x] = '1'
                        if r_y < 8:
                            if floor_map[r_y+1][r_x] == '/':
                                random_roomcount = random.randint(0,3)
                                if random_roomcount == 1:
                                    floor_map[r_y+1][r_x] = '1'
                        if r_y > 0:
                            if floor_map[r_y-1][r_x] == '/':
                                random_roomcount = random.randint(0,3)
                                if random_roomcount == 1:
                                    floor_map[r_y-1][r_x] = '1'
                        if r_x < 8:
                            if floor_map[r_y][r_x+1] == '/':
                                random_roomcount = random.randint(0,3)
                                if random_roomcount == 1:
                                    floor_map[r_y][r_x+1] = '1' 
                        if r_x > 0:
                            if floor_map[r_y][r_x-1] == '/':    
                                random_roomcount = random.randint(0,3)
                                if random_roomcount == 1:
                                    floor_map[r_y][r_x-1] = '1'  
                    
                r_x += 1    
            r_y += 1  
    floor_validate()
```

My game function is a standard while loop with code. I have tried putting `global variable` for each variable in `make_floor_outline` in my game function, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Please update your question with samples of your code which demonstrates the issue you are seeing.

Comment: Where do you define these global variables? The definitions are not shown in your code.

Comment: In my main game definition that isn't shown. I would show it but it is very long and none of the code is relevant.